# How to get a substring from a list of items and assign substring value to the same item in C#

Tags: c#, .net

| StartTime | AgentId |
| --- | --- |
| 08/19/2021 07:04:56 AM UTC | 33 |
| 08/11/2021 02:58:35 PM IST | 42 |
| 08/12/2021 01:01:51 AM CST | 24 |
| 08/12/2021 08:52:34 PM UTC | 61 |

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string  StartTime { get; set; }
  public int      AgentId   { get; set; }
  public string   TimeZone  { get; set; }
  public string   Time      { get; set; }
}
```

I have the above `C#` Class model `MyModel` and its sample data stored as a `List<MyModel>` in my logic. I need a help to parse the `StartTime` field of a list such that, the `TimeZone` field should get the `UTC/CST/IST` of its corresponding `StartTime` and `Time` field of a list should be time stamp from its `StartTime` i,e: `07:04:56` or `02:58:35` and so on. Finally the list should look like something like below:

| StartTime | AgentId | Time | TimeZone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/19/2021 **07:04:56 AM UTC** | 33 | **07:04:56 AM** | **UTC** |
| 08/11/2021 **02:58:35 PM IST** | 42 | **02:58:35 PM** | **IST** |
| 08/12/2021 **01:01:51 AM CST** | 24 | **01:01:51 AM** | **CST** |
| 08/12/2021 **08:52:34 PM UTC** | 61 | **08:52:34 PM** | **UTC** |

Comment: Have you considered using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime` or `string`?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: I have changed the data type to string instead of Datetime

Comment: I need a help in parsing the StartTime field so that the final  c# list should come as the 2nd table

Comment: You use IndexOf and LastIndexOf from the string class to find the first and last space in your string. Then you extract the parts with Substring, or just split the string at the space and take the parts you want from the resulting array

Comment: "I need help" isn't a problem. What can't you figure out about getting some text from a string?

Comment: Are all the fields in your table strings? Are we guaranteed that the formatting is always the same? Have you tried something like this?

    var splitStartTime = startTimeString.Split(' ');
    var time = $"{splitStartTime[1]} {splitStartTime[2]}";
    var timeZone = splitStartTime[3];

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that all of the segments in your `StartTime` property have a forced amount of characters thanks to the string format you've chosen (except for the timezone where we could have e.g. CEST but we don't have to worry about that and I'll get to the why in just a second) we can simply use the `String.Substring` method and for the first parameter, define the character from where the newly to be outputted string should start reading and as the second parameter, the amount of characters it should read from there on out. If we don't set the second parameter the `String.Substring` method will simply read the string to the very end and since the timezone is the last segment of the `StartTime` format, the unknown amount of characters for the timezone is no problem for us.

With that in mind, here are some options you can choose from:

**If you don't want to adjust your class:**

```
private void ManageMyModels(List<MyModel> models)
{
    models.ForEach(model =>
    {
        model.TimeZone = model.StartTime.Substring(23);
        model.Time = model.StartTime.Substring(11, 11);
    });
}
```

This solution is pretty simple as it just iterates over every `MyModel` element and sets the `TimeZone` and `Time` property values accordingly to the `StartTime` value. However, it would be a lot nicer if we didn't always had to do this manually for every model we create so here's a better solution **if you don't mind adjusting your class**:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone => this.StartTime.Substring(23);
    public string Time => this.StartTime.Substring(11, 11);
}
```

The way this solution works is, whenever you access either the `TimeZone` or `Time` property, its assigned code will be executed returning the substring that you need. Performance wise there would be a disadvantage where the code would be executed every time you call either of the properties even when the `StartTime` value hasn't changed.

Alternatively you could do it the other way around where every time you pass a new value to the StartTime both of the properties would be updated as well:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private string _startTime;
    public string StartTime
    {
        get => _startTime;
        set
        {
            this._startTime = value;
            this.TimeZone = value.Substring(23);
            this.Time = value.Substring(11, 11);
        }
    }

    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; private set; }
    public string Time { get; private set; }
}
```

This eliminates previously mentioned disadvantage but creates a new one where the `TimeZone` and `Time` property will always be updated whenever the StartTime property is, even if you wouldn't use it.

Personally, I'd stick to the previous option simply because it's shorter and easier to read.